# Emulate an HID device on windows?

Tags: windows, driver, emulation, hid

I am trying to write a program that emulates a gamepad in such a way that windows recognizes it as a gamepad, but it is actually controlled by my own code.

I have tried to create a virtual COM port and try to make windows recognize it as a gamepad, but without much luck.

Does anyone know a way to do something like this, or could maybe give me some pointers on what might be worth trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HIDUSBFX2 sample driver](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/hidusbfx2) (hidusbfx2.sys) demonstrates how to map a non-HID USB device to a HID device.

**On Windows 10 there is new [Virtual HID Framework (VHF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/virtual-hid-framework--vhf-)** that is intended for same purpose.

Comment: Good answer. Also in that repo I recommend checking out https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/vhidmini2 which has a user mode example. UMDF is slightly easier to debug.